# How to take javascript as InputStream in Jasper Custom Visualization Component?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to integrate D3js with our jasper reports,  the report with d3 charts works when I run it from jasper studio.
But when executing from spring application, the JavaScript file can’t be loaded by the jasper report.

What I am trying to do now is to put the file as input stream in a parameter,

```
parameters.put("res_js_Page2_cell3",cacheService.getJasperInputStream("d3charts/Page2_pie/d3_piechart.min.js"));
```

In report :

```
<cvc:itemProperty name="script">
       <valueExpression><![CDATA[$P{res_js_Page2_cell3}]]></valueExpression>
</cvc:itemProperty>
```

Error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No script provided for the Custom Visualization component.
       at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.customvisualization.fill.CVFillComponent.loadResource(CVFillComponent.java:465)
       at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.customvisualization.fill.CVFillComponent.evaluationPerformed(CVFillComponent.java:327)
       at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.customvisualization.fill.CVFillComponent.evaluateDelayedElement(CVFillComponent.java:257)
       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.resolveElement(JRFillComponentElement.java:219)
       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.performDelayedEvaluation(JRFillElement.java:1131)
       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.resolveElement(JRFillComponentElement.java:212)
       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.ElementEvaluationAction.execute(ElementEvaluationAction.java:69)
       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.DelayedFillActions.runActions(DelayedFillActions.java:269)
       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.resolveBoundElements(BaseReportFiller.java:771)
       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.resolveReportBoundElements(JRBaseFiller.java:1093)
       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillSummary(JRVerticalFiller.java:1047)
       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportEnd(JRVerticalFiller.java:286)
       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:122)
       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:582)
       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:396)
       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:732)
       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:221)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No script provided for the Custom Visualization component. 
       at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.customvisualization.fill.CVFillComponent.loadResource(CVFillComponent.java:456)
       ... 20 more
```

Comment: I would try to pass the URI (as a String) instead of a `InputStream`. I'm not sure where the source code for Custom Visualization Component is but I would not be surprised that they expect a String.

Comment: I tried that with `<cvc:itemProperty name="script" value="d3_piechart.min.js"/>` it only works with studio, with spring boot throws error

 `Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at: d3_piechart.min.js.`

Comment: You need probably to pass correct location relative to application so it can find it, `byte data not found` seems like an error when it attempts to resolve the location. Hence probably you need an URI that if you use in browser finds the script.

Comment: already tried that, doesn't work throws same error. My guess is `cvc:itemProperty` syntax could be wrong for loading JavaScript with `valueExpression`

Comment: seems strange that valueExpression does not work, I still think it's a wrong location error (your are not passing correct URI (String)), but I would need to setup a test environment to check, maybe I will do this for Christmas fun